# Python not decoding json

Tags: python, json, jsonp

I am receiving the error:

```
No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

when trying to parse a json object returned from the xbox music api.

Here is my code:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(SERVICE_API)
conn.request("GET", url)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
j = json.loads(data)
```

the last line is what returned the above error. If I comment that out and print out 'data', I can see the json object. If i copy / past that to jsonlint.com to see if it's valid, it says that it is. I would post it here but it is 800 lines.

Comment: We need to see more than just this piece of code. What is contained in `data` here, exactly? What URL are you calling? Can you give us both `print url` and `print repr(data[:100])`?

Comment: Also, you tagged this with `jsonp`, a very specific protocol that *is not supported by the Python `json` module* (it doesn't need to). Why did you do so?

Comment: There is no code between reading the response and decoding the data - so if you really tried printing it (instead of json loading it) and ran jsonlint over it, the magic pixies must be at work. Tell us the *whole* story

Comment: When I comment out the last line, beginning with 'j' and put a 'print data' above it, the code displayed on my screen is this: http://pastebin.com/WAwW6T6H  ... which is the same code I put in the json validator that came back clean.

Comment: Here is the output of print repr(data[:100])

    '\xef\xbb\xbf{"Albums":{"Items":[{"ReleaseDate":"2013-09-17T00:00:00Z","Duration":"00:45:22","TrackCount":16,"'

Comment: Ok, so after I just pasted the above comment, I noticed the \xef\xbb\xbf stuff, which doesn't show up when I do 'print data'. I changed the data = response.read() line to:

data = response.read().decode("utf-8-sig").encode("utf-8")

and I am no longer getting the original error

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a Microsoft service that includes the UTF-8 BOM at the start. But Microsoft is rather fond of the BOM in UTF-8 (which is entirely redundant here) as it introduced the BOM to UTF-8 to make it easier for Notepad and other Windows applications to auto-detect the encoding used.

Silly Microsoft, that is very much *not valid* according to the JSON RFC; if there is a contact address anywhere you should report this as a bug to them.

You can strip the BOM with:

```
import codecs

data = response.read()
if data.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF8):
    data = data[3:]
```

Comment: Interesting. I will look into this.